# In Java, how can I include dynamic version information in a log file?

Tags: java, logging, manifest

From a Java application I can log a string, using a custom logging framework, as follows:

```
logger.info("Version 1.2 of the application is currently running");
```

Therefore when a user sends me a log file I can easily see what version of the application they are running.

The problem with the code above is that the version is hardcoded in the string literal and someone needs to remember to update it for every release. It's fairly inevitable that updating this string could be forgotten for a release.

What I would like to do is have this string literal automatically updated based on one of the version numbers in the manifest file for the application's JAR:

```
Specification-Version: 1.2
Implementation-Version: 1.2.0.0
```

I don't mind if this happens at compile time or at runtime as long as the version number gets into the log file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard way to get that information is `SomeClass.`[`class`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html)`.`[`getPackage()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getPackage())`.`[`getImplementationVersion()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Package.html#getImplementationVersion()).

There's no need to do any parsing on your own.

Comment: Not sure why but this returns null for me. I've checked the manifest in the generated JAR and it does have the version information. Any ideas?

Comment: Of course "SomeClass" must be loaded from the jar in question.

Comment: I found the problem. The manifest file had a small mistake in the package name. I had 'name: com/company/product' where it should have been 'name: com/company/product/'.

Comment: We set these in the ant script building the jar file.

Comment: Note that this requires `Implementation-Version` to be present on the `MANIFEST.MF`. Some plugins as `maven-assembly-plugin`can modify it and not include this entry by default inside the JAR.

Comment: @KingMidas: yes, but the question explicitly states that they want to read that information.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the manifest at runtime using the following class

```
public class ManifestFinder {

    private final Class<?> _theClass;


    public ManifestFinder(Class<?> theClass) {

        _theClass = theClass;
    }


    public Manifest findManifest() throws MalformedURLException, IOException {

        String className = _theClass.getSimpleName();
        String classFileName = className + ".class";
        String pathToThisClass = _theClass.getResource(classFileName).toString();

        int mark = pathToThisClass.indexOf("!");
        String pathToManifest = pathToThisClass.toString().substring(0, mark + 1);
        pathToManifest += "/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF";
        return new Manifest(new URL(pathToManifest).openStream());

    }

}
```

parse the data from the manifest ( untested )

```
 String specificationVersion = manifest.getMainAttributes().getValue("Implementation-Version");
```

and then include the parsed version in the log statement

```
logger.info("Version " + specificationVersion + " of the application is currently running");
```

See [the Jar file specification](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/jar/jar.html) for more details.

Comment: Minor mistake. Missing slash at start of resource name.
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");

Comment: Actually there is something funny going on. This is giving me the Java API Manifest: Manifest <Specification-Title: Java Platform API Specification> & <Specification-Version: 1.5>

Comment: When multiple JARs are used? How do you know you are getting the version from the right JAR?

Comment: It all depends on the classloader, but url class loaders in particular fulfill the requirements.

Answer (score -1):

so you can load your /META-INF/MANIFEST at runtime, using the ClassLoader. Then load and parse `Implementation-Version`:

```
String welcome = String.format("Version %s of the application is currently running",
                          implementationVersion);
logger.info(welcome);
```

Comment: An actual code example that demonstrates use of ClassLoader would be more helpful. The actual string format command is not that helpful without knowing how to use ClassLoader.